# updating mysql with latest mariadb

Tags: mariadb, uwamp

I installed uWamp 3.1.0 but the php versions are quite old. I coulg update PHP to 7.4.4 using instructions found here. I tried the same with mariadb 10.4 butting the 32bit versione in bin\database\mariadb-10.4.12 and copuing my_uwamp.ini from old mysql 5 folder but the engine doesn't start.
Any hint?

Comment: Don't use the 32-bit version unless you have less than 4GB of RAM and a 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

If uwamp is running , stop services and close down.

At the time of writing this I am going to refer to the stable 10.4.12 version
Download the version of mariadb that you want to use. Download the .zip version instead of the installer.

https://downloads.mariadb.org/interstitial/mariadb-10.4.12/win32-packages/mariadb-10.4.12-win32.zip/from/http%3A//ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/mariadb/

Go to your installed uwamp directory and click through to the bin/database directory
Create a directory / folder name of mariadb-10.4.12 
Expand the files in to this directory

You now need to copy the data directory for the mysql-5.7.11 to the mariadb-10.4.12

This is due to uwamp creating special users to shutdown the sql server

Now create a file called my_uwamp.ini and save it in the mariadb-10.4.12 directory with your favourite text editor

Copy the text in between the ################## below and save as my_uwmap.ini

```
''''    
##################
#
# Lots more settings can be configured from 
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/
# Based on mariaDB 10.x and above
#
# When uwamp loads it will create the my.ini in the root mariadb directory and substitute the variables for the correct paths

# The MariaDB server
[mariadb]

# Directory where you want to put your data

datadir={MYSQLDATAPATH}
# Directory for the errmsg.sys file in the language you want to use
language={MYSQLPATH}/share/english

# This is the prefix name to be used for all log, error and replication files
log_basename=mariadb-error
log_error={MYSQLPATH}/mariadb-errors.log
# Enable logging by default to help find problems
general_log
log-slow-queries

##################
''''
```

This is the configuration file that uwamp looks for at startup and then substitutes the variables and saves as the my.ini in the mariadb-10.4.12 directory

You will be required to update the phpmyadmin application, this is stored in /uwamp/phpapps directory

Download the latest phpmyadmin package 
https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.0.2/phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-all-languages.zip

Rename the /uwamp/phpapps/phpmyadmin directory to phpmyadmin-old or phpmyadmin.old
Create a new phpmyadmin directory and expand the files in to the phpmyadmin directory

Load up uwamp and select the mariadb in the sql dropdown.
There should be no errors reported in the log window.

Finally click on the MYSQL Config button

leave the old password as root
new password as ->  root
reenter password as - > root

click on the OK button. Be patient as wait till the save has completed, this is just to update the uwamp user to assist with shutdown.

Now the default myphpadmin access should be set to username root and password root

You should be good to go ! If any problems drop us a line on here :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for precious information!

Actual MariaDB distribution does not accept [log-slow-queries] parameter.
Instead, [slow_query_log] is supported.

Working template therefore would be:

```
##################
#
# Lots more settings can be configured from 
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/
# Based on mariaDB 10.x and above
#
# When uwamp loads it will create the my.ini in the root mariadb directory and substitute the variables for the correct paths

# The MariaDB server
[mariadb]

# Directory where you want to put your data

datadir={MYSQLDATAPATH}
# Directory for the errmsg.sys file in the language you want to use
language={MYSQLPATH}/share/english

# This is the prefix name to be used for all log, error and replication files
log_basename=mariadb-error
log_error={MYSQLPATH}/mariadb-errors.log
# Enable logging by default to help find problems
general_log
slow_query_log
##################
```